# CI/CD for Xamarin mobile apps - alternative to deprecated AppCenter & Bitrise

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, bitrise

**AppCenter** is no longer recommended for production use for CI/CD of **Xamarin** mobile apps (also is full problems) - not sure if this is a public information but we got this information from Microsoft.

**Bitrise** recently announced that it's deprecating **Xamarin** in their CI/CD process (as of 2022). [Link to the article](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/xamarin/index/#deprecating-xamarin-on-bitrise)

My question is - is there any CI/CD alternative to Bitrise & AppCenter other than GitHub actions (however not sure if that will work for us correctly). At least for the automated build part?

I acknowledge that this is not yes/no answer but I would be grateful for any recommendation for a full supported alternative.

Comment: Lots of options. Azure DevOps, GitHub Actions, TeamCity on own agents, GitLab (I think their macOS hosted builds might still be in beta). There are probably more out there. When Bitrise says they are removing steps for Xamarin, that doesn't make it impossible to build a Xamarin App. It is easy to install the tools yourself, especially with .NET6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft's Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) supports pipelines for Xamarin apps that can easily be used for CI/CD as well as app deployment